# Finding common elements for multiple lines in a text file

Tags: awk, text-processing

Assuming File.txt like below:

```
A1 B C D 
E F C H
C J 
A2 F B
D J C 
F T Y U I
B C N J Y
```

What I need is to check for the lines starting with pattern "^A" and then look for the elements after that (from $2 to the end of line). Then I need to find the common elements in lines starting with these elements. Here is the output for File.txt:

```
A1 C J
A2 Y
```

or

```
A1 J C
A2 Y
```

The order of common elements (e.g. J and C) in output does not matter.

P.S. Awk is preferred.

Comment: Is not clear what you mean. Also, what did you try so far? Having an [amount of questions in awk](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3684042+[awk]) so far, you should know how to start from :)

Comment: For every `A*` line you want to print out all the elements common between the line contents of every line that starts with an element equal to the elements of the `A*` line in question?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Exactly.

Comment: @fedorqui: I am in the middle of my code. I'll post it here when I am done.

Comment: Why does `C` show up on the `A1` output line? Does the initial field of the desired lines count?

Comment: @Etan Reisner: Yes. It does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU awk for true 2D arrays and delete array and length(array):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) children[$1][$i] }
/^A/{ parents[$1]; delete children[$1][$1] }
END {
    for (parent in parents) {
        delete count
        printf "%s", parent
        for (child in children[parent])
            for (grandchild in children[child])
                if (++count[grandchild] == length(children[parent]))
                    printf " %s", grandchild
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A1 C J
A2 Y
```

It works by just checking that the count for the number of occurrences of any field in the non-A lines matches the count of the 2nd+ fields in the A lines since that says it occurs in every case.

Comment: What if I want to get the grandchildren from another file? I mean What if we record the parents and their children from file1 and then look for grandchildren in fileB? I have already tried to modify your code by adding FNR==NR to the first line, and "; next;" after "children[$1][$1]" in second line. I also added "{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) Allchildren[$1][$i]}" before "END" and modified lines 8 and 9 like "for (grandchild in Allchildren[child])" and " if (++count[grandchild] == length(Allchildren[parent]))" . Could you please let me know where I have done wrong?

Comment: Don't change anything it'll work as-is as there's nothing in that script that cares about how many separate input files you have. Just add whatever files you like to the arg list `awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3 ...`. If that DOESN'T work then update your question to show some sample input and expected output and clarify your new requirements.

Comment: @ Ed Morton: Thank you so much. I could edit your program to adjust requirements of my problem. Thanks for your attention. Your programming style is a very good sample to follow while learning awk.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit ugly and I feel like it should be doable in a cleaner way but it works on the sample data at least.

```
/^A/ {
    amap[$1]=NF - 1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        rmap[$i]=rmap[$i] (rmap[$i]?SUBSEP:"") $1
    }
    next
}

$1 in rmap {
    split(rmap[$1], a, SUBSEP)
    for (f in a) {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            afmap[a[f],$i]++
        }
    }
}

END {
    for (af in afmap) {
        split(af, a, SUBSEP)
        if (afmap[af] == amap[a[1]]) {
            o[a[1]]=o[a[1]] (o[a[1]]?" ":"") a[2]
        }
    }
    for (f in o) {
        print f, o[f]
    }
}
```